# Vilified by community in Original Fallout?

Tags: fallout

I can't get into Junktown because I accidentally walked inside when it was night and they don't allow travellers in at night. Now, whenever I try to get inside, all the guards are trying to kill me. I've waited weeks (in game) and they still hate me!

How do I stop them hating me so I can get in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, unfortunately. Your best bet is to just make use of your stealth skill and sneak past where possible.

There is nothing crucial to the main storyline in Junktown though, so if you're worried from this point of view, you can just continue on with your quest.